# '.' is not reconized as an internal or external command

Tags: c, windows

after compiling the hello.c ,when i try to run it using ./a.out ,it says the following 
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
here are the system variables 
Path:C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin;C:\Program Files\MinGW\bin;

Comment: You are using a UNIX command on Windows. You do not need `./` on Windows, because the current folder is implicitly on the path.

Comment: I advise you to use a IDE instead of doing things from the command prompt.

Comment: thanks  dasblinkenlight , actually  i am new in this

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: correct, but the error is not `.`, it is the forward slash. `.\a.out` would work ... except, surely the executable is not called `a.out`?

Comment: I wish you would try Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename a.out to a.exe and run it using .\a.exe or just a.exe

Make sure that the current directory contains a.exe

Comment: If it's .exe you can run `a`, `.\a`, or `"./a"`. If it's .out, you don't have to rename it; just run `a.out`, `.\a.out`, or `"./a.out"`. Actually, if you add `;.OUT` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable, you can omit the extension in this case, too. Quoting the path with double quotes is required if forward slash (/) is used as the path separator.

Comment: @eryksun You do not have to rename it on Linux. You can just run ./a.out. This is so because Linux relies on the file magic number. Windows relies on the file extension to determine the file type. As such, you have to rename it with the exe extension. To run it, you can type .\a or .\a.exe or a or a.exe assuming the current folder contains the file. Alternatively,  you can run the file using the full file path c:\...\...\a.exe or without extension.

Comment: You don't have to rename the file on Windows. You can directly run a file named `a.out` in the command prompt. It tries `CreateProcess` before it tries `ShellExecuteEx`. Since this .out file is a PE executable, `CreateProcess` succeeds. `ShellExecuteEx` is what uses the filetype (based on the extension association and the perceived type) to find a command to run. All the command prompt uses regarding extensions is `PATHEXT` to allow omitting the extension when running a program.

Comment: By "command prompt *uses*" I meant "directly uses".  Obviously if it falls back on calling `ShellExecuteEx` that will use the extension, but that's not specific to cmd. Any process that calls `shell32!ShellExecuteEx` will get the same result.

Comment: @eryksun I only use Linux at home. I will rename a exe file with a out extension and will try to execute it from cmd and see what happens. Obviously,  that's what the question was about. As far as system calls are concerned,  I have not read the Windows API documentation, but do not think it is relevant to this question.

Comment: The API that gets called is relevant. If `ShellExecuteEx` is called *first*, then whatever filetype is associated with the .out file extension determines that command that executes. It's only because the cmd shell always tries `CreateProcess` *first* that we know a PE executable will execute normally regardless of the file extension.